# How to calculate a polynomial equation in haskell

Tags: haskell

Basically I need to calculate a polynomial in haskell based on a value x, and the values of the coeficients need to be stored in a list of tupples.

So for example the polynomial *f*(*x*) = *a*·*x*<sup>*n*</sup> + *a*<sub>1</sub>·*x*<sup>*n*−1</sup> + ... + *a*<sub>*n*−1</sub>·*x* + *a*<sub>*n*</sub> will be represented in a list of tuples like `f = [(a0, n), (a1, n-1), ... , (an-1, 1), (an, 0)]` , so if I want to calculate 
`2*x^2 + 3*x + 3` for `x=20` I will need the list `[(2,2), (3,1) , (0,3)]`.

Thanks a lot in advance and sorry if I explained this exercise in a messy way :)

Comment: `calc f x = sum (map (\(coef, exp) -> coef * x ^ exp) f)`

Comment: `[(2,2),(3,1),(0,3)]` should be `[(2,2),(3,1),(3,0)]`

Comment: Read up on [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) for a more efficient way to compute the value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a basic solution, try using explicit recursion:

```
evaluate :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int
evaluate []             _x = .... -- TODO (1)
evaluate ((a,n) : rest)  x = .... -- TODO (2)
   where
   result = evaluate rest x
```

Above, in `(1)` we need to specify what is the result of evaluating an "empty" polynomial (with no coefficients at all). This is the base case of our recursion.

Instead, `(2)` is the recursive step. Here, we split the coefficients-pairs into the first `(a,n)`, and the rest of the list `rest`. We then recursively define `result = evaluate rest x` to evaluate the polynomial "without the first coefficient", that is *a*<sub>1</sub>·*x*<sup>*n*−1</sup> + ... + *a*<sub>*n*−1</sub>·*x* + *a*<sub>*n*</sub>.
Then, in line `(2)` we need to combine this `result` with the first monomial, evaluated in `x`.

You should now be able to fill the dots.

Answer (score 0):

Easy: just fold over the list. The accumulator function should add the current term (solved for x) to the accumulate. The seed needs to be 0, of course.

Comment: Sorry I dont know what folding is (it's my 3rd day of studying haskell)

Comment: @Alex I was trolling a bit ;) Since you didn't tell us what you have tried, I gave the shortest answer I could come up with.

Comment: ok, fair enough

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
> peval p x = foldr (\(a,n) s -> s+(a*x^n)) 0 p
> poly = peval [(2,2),(3,1),(3,0)]
> map poly [0..5]

[3,8,17,30,47,68]
```